# getexternalstoragedirectory is showing self and emulated directories only

Tags: android, kotlin, storage

I'm trying to get the Download Folder to show on my file explorer. However on Android 9, when I use the getexternalstoragedirectory() method is showing self and emulated directories only and if I press "emulated" I cannot see more folders, it shows an empty folder.

So this is how I'm getting the path, it's working fine in other Android versions but Android 9. Any guide would be appreciated

```
val dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).absolutePath
```

Comment: Could the problem be in your device or emulator? I checked it and there is no problem. I can access the files and I can also see the device file explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what's the use you're giving to the path. are you saving this path in shared preferences and using it later?

Make sure there is not old data saved for your app in the device, if you have, even after uninstalling and installing again the problem will be there. Make sure your path is not loaded from local data. If so,  you have to clear the data manually and later set the allowbackup flag within the Manifest to FALSE. Check the official documentation for backup tag in [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element)

Saved data paths can cause weird behaviour if the path does not exist anymore and you are trying to using it later.

Let me know if this helps.

```
<application
    android:name="com.name.xxx.YouApp"
    android:allowBackup="false"
```

Comment: Thanks @hermes I'm in fact saving the path in shared preferences and using it later in my flow. I'll check this and get back

Comment: The shared preferences were the problem indeed and not the way I was getting the Path. This saved my life, thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you know about this might be the problem?

Comment: I've got a similar problem before. Great I could help

Answer (score 0):

Well, Android 9 (API 28) should not have this problem. However, as the Android docs specify, [getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) has been deprecated in `Android Q` (ndroid 10 - API 29) you can however use [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) with [Relative Path](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#RELATIVE_PATH) ( Added in API level 29 ) to access `Downloads` directory.

Since `Relative Path` is applicable only for API level 29 and above, you may want to use it for API 29 and above and use `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` for older APIs. (Assuming that you have used necessary Read/Write permissions)

So your code could be something similar to this -

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
    val resolver = context.contentResolver    
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
          }
    val uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), contentValues)
}else{
    val dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).absolutePath
}
```

You can get more details about accessing media form shared storage here - [Access media files from shared storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and get back

Comment: Thanks @Manish after trying your solution still not working. I still only see "self" and "emulated" directories and cannot see content if I select either of the paths

Answer (score 0):

On some devices and in newer Android versions `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` no longer returns a valid path. Try using `Context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` instead, it should return this path: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/your.package.name/`.

Try it out to see if thats the issue. Here's the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()).

Source: From the accepted answer of this [Issue writing in the Download directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658374/issue-writing-in-the-download-directory/60779457)

Comment: thanks @biscuit but I need to access Shared directory,Not the directory within the app.

Comment: Here is a great response that could guide you https://stackoverflow.com/a/58235912/6074224

Comment: @FantomasMex have you find a solution?

Comment: No yet @biscuit

Comment: im not gonna flag you cause thats not how I roll. but next time have the decency to at least change a word or two XD.

Comment: I though I did, I usually do make a link to the answer, my bad, I've edited it

Answer (score 0):

try this `Context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`

there is a link with the answer in kotlin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58575031/10637400)

and weirdly enough the best [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.context.getexternalfilesdir?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9) on this i found were from microsoft

Comment: Thanks but I've tried this before. I think this could be and android Bug.

Comment: have you tried using the kotlin code? i.e. val downloadFolder = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) and then downloadFolder.listFiles(). have you tried with a different device?

Comment: what about turning the following string into a file '/storage/emulated/0/Download' (notice there is no s after download)