# getExternalStorageDirectory deprecated in Android 10

Tags: android, kotlin, android-external-storage, android-10.0, android-storage

I am trying to generate a file name to save an AR Model using ARCore and Kotlin.

Since Android 10  the Environment methods `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`  and `getExternalStorageDirectory()`    were deprecated for privacy concerns.

What can be a replacement for the following code?

```
private fun generateFileName() : String {
        val date = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", java.util.Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
        return Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + "CardAR/" + date + "_screenshot.jpg"
    }
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: The same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60863310/8956604)

Answer (score 1):

```
private File getAbsoluteFile(String relativePath, Context context) {
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
        return new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), relativePath);
    } else {
        return new File(context.getFilesDir(), relativePath);
    }
}
```

This method will return the full path to the file.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` you can now use `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658374/issue-writing-in-the-download-directory/60720064) are a few answers that might help you.